# Good idea / Bad idea (/other ideas ?)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, javafx

I have recently been asked to make an Eclipse Rcp view that would be "pretty".
In that purpose I had fist looked at Java2D (after my boss advised me so) before the client's query turned to be more like

"It would be *smooth* if you could do some flash or something ..."

From there JavaFx seemed appealing to me however I never had a chance to use it before. I then were wondering if before to dive "head first" anyone (who would have preferably used it seriously) had any advice, warning or any constructive comment to do about using this product in an RCP view (so based on SWT).

I really long to know if JavaFx meets it's promises.

Thanks in advance and have a good day !

[EDIT]I dont want an Eclipse Fancy skinning or to make views appear with light effects or in a CompizFusion way,

What I want is to display fancy animations and pretty visual effects within a specific view that will be called sometimes. (Sorry I wasn't clear in the first place :s)[/EDIT]

*I'll pass on the "What's pretty and what's not ?" and other "Tastes are a personnal thing" debates, here "pretty" simply means to qualify a view containing convoluted transparancies and subtle animations ...

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse RCP can also be customized in the way it looks, e.g. when you dont want to have the Eclipsi-L&F. Its called **Presentation API**, I saw a quite amazing UI once in a presentation but I cannot find it right now. Anyway, I just want to point you the direction, since I personally havent used this API (yet).

There are also some "skins" available for download.

1. [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/presentation_shelf/presentation_shelf.php)
2. [MP3 Manager](http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/mp3m)

EDIT: Just found the [slides](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/*checkout*/org.eclipse.ui.examples.presentation/eclipsecon2005-presentationsAPI.ppt?rev=1.1&content-type=application/powerpoint). It goes quite into detail, but when you have a look at the last slide...it doesnt look like the Eclipse you know :-)

Comment: To both gizmo & lostiniceland : Thanks for your answers but my problem is not to make an eclipse application that looks good at any moment of it's use but a single view that will sometimes display fancy animations and nice visual effects, it is a view that will be called  sometimes(and has to be called inside the Eclipse application) to display a presentation depending on the loaded plugins in Eclipse. Eclipse must look the same as usual, only this viem must show nice animations ...

Comment: hmmm...is this view like the "Welcome Page" in Eclipse (since you mention it as a presentation page)? Because this is just an HTML page but you can set it up in a way that each plugin contributes to it (like when you install Mylin in Eclipse, it ads its own content to the welcome). And since it is html you should be able to add any presentation-framework. 

Or is this view dependent on functionality from the plugins? Then maybe the GEF can help you. Here is an example: http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/images/zest_screenshot.jpg

Comment: Yes it is more like your second option, my plugins have to contribute to the presentation, of course an HTML based thing would have been nice but my presentation will have to trigger Eclipses commandes, have to be contributed, so I left the SWT.Browser option aside ...

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX uses Swing as default layout engine, so you'll gain nothing using it rather than Java2D.

On the other hand, using either your home-grown toolkit or Swing is generally a bad idea when working with Eclipse, as it already embeds the SWT toolkit. The main advantage of SWT over Swing is that it use the OS native widgets. Using another toolkit will lead to the following issues:

- Poor integration with Eclipse look&feel.
- Poor integration with Eclipse views and editors management.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. No, you can't use JavaFX yet. The problem is that JFX script can't be embedded into Swing nor Eclipse SWT. We already know about such an issues. (The is some kind of hack how to embed JFX into Swing APP only.)